# Share some part of screen using webrtc

Tags: javascript, php, webrtc, navigator

I need help in webRTC.
I am developing an application in which I need to share only some part of screen using webRTC.
I am able to share whole screen using it.
But I want to share some element of screen.
Anyone can help me please?

Comment: Check [this out](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/part-of-screen-sharing). You can take screenshots of specific sections of the screen and then send the pictures over a datachannel and display them.

Comment: I tried that, but I can't do something like that first I take screenshot of my screen and then I send it to other. When I am in conference at that time I want to share my presentation part of screen with others.

Comment: You can take numerous screenshots (15 a second or so) and send each one so that it is like a live feed. But if that will not work, I am not sure there are media constraints for the screenCapture in Chrome that allows you to specify pixel locations.

Comment: That's the main issues that chrome doesn't allow to specify pixel locations, even its not allowing whole tab sharing, if we want to use it than we need to share whole screen. Anyways thanks.

Comment: Request a chrome bug for an additional feature. I am sure this is something that they would like to implement eventually.

Answer (score 1):

I was experimenting with this some time ago and came up with this. Maybe it will help.
Chrome only!

https://andersevenrud.github.io/webrtc-screenshare-crop/

**Edit:** [Uploaded the source to github](https://github.com/andersevenrud/webrtc-screenshare-crop-demo) and created a full implementation example -- it comes with some limitations (image size over RTC), but those can be solved.